# Error when deployed web service restful in tomcat 6 and centos

Tags: java, rest, tomcat6, centos6

when I implement a RESTful web service to tomcat6 in server test, everything went well (with the creation of virtual host in server.xml). But when he showed up real server with a similar configuration. detail:

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:519)
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:274)
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)

root cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/FTPSchedulerWeb/org/apache/jsp/default_jsp.java
     java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
     java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
     java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:70)
     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:188)
     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:461)
     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:442)
     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:430)
     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:274)
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error indicates that there was no default.jsp Are you sure that you navigated to the same location? Is there any difference in web.xml? Show us your configuration in the index section.

Comment: The problem is that everything is fine when in sever tests, such defective only when the server actually.
What I discovered is tomcat can not create folders (configuration in server.xml file name) in the work folder when it worked. in tomcat web server had such a run it, add 1 hour web anymore it is not.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Is it a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like so: I copy the folder of the currently running a project of the corrupted folder, then edit some web defective ones. Then restart tomcat, things have run